# 2 where clauses slower than separated queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, google-cloud-sql, database-performance

I'm using Google Cloud SQL (the micro server version) to run a couple of performance tests.

I want to do the following query:

```
select count(*) from table where A = valueA and B like "%input_string%";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   512997 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.64 sec)
```

If I run them separately, I get:

```
select count(*) from table where A = valueA;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   512998 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.18 sec)

select count(*) from table where B like "%input_string%";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   512997 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.43 sec)
```

How is that difference in performance possible???

Both A and B columns have indexes as they are used to order tables in a web application.

Thx!
EDIT:
table schema

```
table | CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `B` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `A` (`A`),
  KEY `B` (`B`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=512999 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: As with any query optimization question, we can only guess unless you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` and `EXPLAIN <query>` for each query.

Comment: update your question and add  also  the table schema

Comment: you can't really optimize it `LIKE "%...%"` constructs can never really use a index.. LIKE "...%" can only make use of a index.. Even if you would do `KEY(A, b)` the query can only use the A "part" of the index... Adding a `FULLTEXT` index and using `MATCH()` is most likely better to use here..

Comment: are you sure that no caching is playing a role in performance.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @AndrésBiarge The InnoDB buffer cache greatly affects the performance of a query. The first time a query is run the cache is populated with the relevant records. Future runs of the query will often be faster than that initial run. Therefore, to benchmark properly, always run the query at least twice, and discard the first result.

Comment: Ah, ok. Yeah, I know, but the best result I can get thanks to caching is around 5-6 segs. Also, there are parameters that depend on user input from a web application, so probably each query would be unique or quite different from each other

Comment: "The InnoDB buffer cache greatly affects the performance of a query" @WillemRenzema yes but i don't think a `COUNT(*)` query would warm up the buffers.. ideally you should need to use `SELECT * FROM table` without a `WHERE` to get data into the buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A option might be using a `FULLTEXT INDEX` and using `MATCH()` on it.

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `B` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY(A), 
  FULLTEXT INDEX(B)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=512999 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And a query rewrite

```
SELECT 
 count(*)
FROM 
`table`
WHERE
   A = 'A'
 AND 
   B IN (

     SELECT 
      B
     FROM 
      `table`
     WHERE
   MATCH(B) AGAINST('+input_string' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
```

The inner SQL will filter down a possible result based on the FULLTEXT index. 
And the outer SQL will do the other filtering.

You could also use a `UNION ALL` now i think about it. 
It should work on this questions `CREATE TABLE` statement . 
The general idea is to get two counts for both filters and pick the lowest as valid count.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 MIN(counted) AS 'COUNT(*)' # Result 512997
FROM (

  select count(*) AS counted from `table` where A = 'A' # Result 512998
  UNION ALL
  select count(*)  from `table` where B like "%input_string%" # Result  512997
) AS counts
```

Comment: Just tested it and it performs better (3 segs instead of 10). However, there are fewer matches: the initial query matches 500+k rows while using MATCH...AGAINST matches 170k rows

Comment: You mean you get different results? @AndrésBiarge between your query and this one?

Comment: I don't think I'm following you. I'm not using the EXPLAIN command, I'm running the whole query as you suggested and I'm getting different results, yes

Comment: Right i see now possibly why, try `MATCH(B) AGAINST('+input_string' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` or `AGAINST ('input_string' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)` which should also work

Comment: Just tried. Same... different results. I've tried using NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE too and still get less results

Comment: @AndrésBiarge i accidentally seamed to have used the `id`  column in the SQL `AND 
   id IN ( SELECT id ...)` instead of using the B column i've edited the question.. If that still does not help i think your B column might contain words shorter then the [ft_min_word_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) config or contains [stop words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

Comment: your last edit gets even slower :( but you've pointed me into some stuff I didn't know, so thank you very much. I'll keep investigating!

Comment: @AndrésBiarge check mine edit about using `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

Did you run each timing twice?  If not, there could be caching involved that confuses you.

`where A = valueA and B like "%input_string%";` begs for `INDEX(A, B)`.  Note:  That composite index is *not* equivalent to your two separate indexes.

If you go with a `FULLTEXT` index on `B`, then this would be simpler:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t
    WHERE MATCH(B) AGAINST('+input_string' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      AND A = valueA
```

(The use of a subquery should be unnecessary and slower.)